# Revert/remove specific Git commit on specific branch using SourceTree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I use BitBucket and SourceTree. I have two branches called `Dev_1.2.2` and `Dev_1.2.3`

I committed some files on `Dev_1.2.2` but did not push. I don't want to commit or push these files on `Dev_1.2.2`, I made commit successfully thus files on `Dev_1.2.3` but can't revert/remove the commit from `Dev_1.2.2`.

How can I revert this commit from the branch using SourceTree?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly:  you have two branches.  You don't want to push it, but you did some other work on another branch.  Now, you can't revert the changes from the first branch?  How did you create the second branch?  Was it a part of the first branch?

Comment: Dev_1.2.3 is created from Dev_1.2.2 and Dev_1.2.3 is latest copy. I do some work on Dev_1.2.2 and make commit (on my local server) not pull to live(Bitbucket).

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what you're asking but I can see two options:

## Reverse the commit

To reverse the specific commit in SourceTree, do the following:

- Check out the `Dev_1.2.2` branch by double-clicking it in the list of branches on the left.
- In the commit history graph, select the commit in question.
- Right-click the commit, and select "Reverse commit..." from the context menu.
- Confirm the action in the displayed confirmation dialog.

That should do it, it will create a reversal commit. Your history will now show that you first added the files, and then a second commit showing that you removed them again.

## Reset to previous commit

If you want to get rid of the whole commit without it showing in history, you can reset the branch to the commit before you added the files.

To do that, you need to do the following:

- Check out the `Dev_1.2.2` branch by double-clicking it in the list of branches on the left.
- In the commit history graph, find the commit in question.
- Next, select the commit immediately before you added the files. Make sure it's in the same branch.
- Right-click that commit, then select "Reset Dev_1.2.2 to this commit".
- In the next dialog, select the "Hard" option and confirm the action.

Warning: This will mean you lose any changes made after the selected commit. Your branch will be reset to this commit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Rebase children of [commit hash] interactively" on a commit that is below the one you want to delete.

Then use "delete selected".

Note, this rewrites the commit date, which you can fix from command line using `git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date [commit hash]`.

After rebase, you will need to `git push --force`.

Answer (score 0):

## **How to Delete a Commit from Source Tree**

1. Select the commit you want to go back to
2. Right-click and choose the option “Reset current branch to this commit”
3. In using mode choose “Mixed - keep working copy but reset index”
4. Select your branch and choose option Push to → {branch}
5. Make sure Force Push option is checked
6. Push your changes

[git](/questions/tagged/git)[sourcetree](/questions/tagged/sourcetree)

Answer (score -3):

Use the below command

git reset --hard **commit_id**